# Looking for source: "How not to be a graduate student"

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

I remember having read, about 15 years ago, a transcript of a lecture given by Richard K. Guy, titled "How not to be a graduate student". He gave lots of advice, mostly humorous, concealing sharp and deep observations.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate this text on the Internet; I have the feeling I had read it in a newsgroup list, and these things don't seem to exist anymore.

Does anyone perchance have a copy of this?

Comment: Professor Khan in this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00283-016-9674-x) mentions the talk, you might try emailing him to inquire if he has a copy.

Comment: Apparently it was a public lecture at a 2009 conference at Calgary. See https://www.pims.math.ca/files/CYRC_2009_Final_Report.pdf for a mention of the talk (but not a transcript, nor a link to one).

Comment: Any change you were able to locate the transcript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to locate it, \TeX ed it, and uploaded it to https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/bartholdi/pub/Guy-NotGrad.pdf

Comment: Genius! I did find one deliberately true statement: "It's impossible to write a mathematics book without making mistakes."

Comment: Is it just me or the link does not work?

Comment: It's back online.